# Is there an easy way to show that $g_k(x) := (1-x)^n x^k$ converges uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n \in \Bbb N_0$ be constant and

$$g_k: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R, k \in \Bbb N$$

$$g_k(x) := (1-x)^n x^k.$$

Is there an easy way to show that this sequence converges uniformly? The solution I saw was highly complicated and worked with local and global extrem points, but I don't believe that one has to do it like this.

Since $(1-x)^n \in [0,1]$, we know that

$$(1-x)^nx^k \le x^k.$$

Now, if we could find a boundary that is independent from $x$, we would be done, wouldn't we? In this case, we want to assume that $g := 0$, so

$$|g_k(x) - g(x)| = |g_k(x)|.$$

Comment: Use the supremum definition.

Comment: If you know Dini's theorem, that makes it very easy.

Comment: No, the class I'm tutoring just started with sequences of functions. For me, the solution our T.A. gave us for this excercise just seems very weird.

Comment: The exponent n doesn't play any role, so you could first show that $g_k(x)<=f_k(x):=(1-x)x^k$ and then show the uniform convergence of $f_k$. This makes the search of the supremum easier (less exponentiation). Or if you use the strategy with two cases as in my answer below, the boundary $x_\epsilon:=1-\epsilon$ would be easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think looking for the global extremum is particularly complex, but if you don't like proceding that way you could find a boundary by separating two cases:

$\forall\epsilon>0$, let $x_\epsilon=1-\epsilon^\frac{1}{n}\in (0,1)$

Then $\forall x, 0<x<1$:

- If $x<x_\epsilon$, $g_k(x)<x^k<x_\epsilon^k<\epsilon$ for all $k$ bigger that some $k_\epsilon$ since $x_\epsilon^k\rightarrow 0$
- If $x>=x_\epsilon$, $g_k(x)<(1-x_\epsilon)^n<\epsilon$

Hence $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists k_\epsilon, \forall k>k_\epsilon, \forall x \in (0,1), g_k(x)<\epsilon$

Which proves the uniform convergence to $g_n=0$.